# SQL, add column with summed values of the same type

Tags: mysql, sql

My current table looks like this:

```
ID   TYPE   QUANTITY   
1    A1     3
2    B1     2
3    A1     2
4    B1     8
```

And after doing the query I want to get that:

```
ID   TYPE   QUANTITY   SUM   
1    A1     3          5
2    B1     2          10
3    A1     2          5
4    B1     8          10
```

The SUM column consist of summed quantities of items with the same type.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.ID,t.TYPE,t.QUANTITY,x.SUM FROM TABLE t LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID,TYPE,QUANTITY,SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM FROM TABLE GROUP BY TYPE)x
ON t.type=x.type
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6d4e/6)

Comment: Thank you guys, each solution is great, although they are very similar. Sorry that I can't add you points because of my low rep ;)

Answer (score 2):

My approach is to use a derived table which aggregates the quantity by type first and then join this result with the original data:

```
select
    t.id,
    t.type,
    t.quantity,
    tmp.overall

from
    table t join (
        select
            table.type,
            sum(table.quantity) as overall

        from
            table

        group by
            table.type
    ) tmp on t.type = tmp.type
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the query but see what happens if you do this:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  myTable.TYPE, 
  QUANTITY, 
  aaa.summy 
FROM myTable
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    TYPE, 
    SUM(QUANTITY) summy 
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY TYPE
) aaa
ON aaa.TYPE = myTable.TYPE
```

Comment: @Strawberry I created the table to test the query.  I have now updated it :)